# How do I get Postgres to return the complete row?

Tags: postgresql

I am inserting a record and returning the new id:

```
INSERT INTO USERS (firstName, lastName) VALUES ($1, $2) returning user_id
```

Is there a way to return the whole user row?  I know I can do a `SELECT` on the `user_id` I am returning, but that seems like the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: why you think that it is wrong?

Comment: It just seems there should be a way to say `returning user` or concise like that.

Comment: so, read the docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-insert.html

Comment: the insert statement inserts a row, so if you like to return anything it just have to be like a select, for your case `returning *` it will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
RETURNING *
```

though, like with a `SELECT`, it's generally better practice to be explicit and name the desired columns, so later schema changes don't break anything.

BTW, please post `\d tablename` or `CREATE TABLE` info for the schema you refer to in future; you might know what `user_id` is, but we just have to guess based on the query if you don't tell us.

Comment: That is a great idea.  I will post the schema from now on.